SQL query performance: condition within JOIN ON vs WHERE clause
We have millions of rows in a table. We don't have direct SQL Server access, so I'm unable to see the execution plan. Which query is more optimized in SQL Server?
Condition within JOIN ON clause:
SELECT 
    E.[ENTITY_ID] ENTITY_ID, E.[ENTTY_NM] ENTTY_NM, 
    G.[PRNT_ID] GCC_ID, G.[PRNT_NM] GCC_NM, 
    E.[Buba_ID] BUBA_ID, E.[GRP_TTL_DBT] GRP_TTL_DBT, 
    E.[INTRNL_RTNG_CD] INTRNL_RTNG,
    COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM 
    {ENTITI} E
INNER JOIN 
    {GCC_ENTITY} GE ON (E.[ID] = GE.[ENTITYID]) 
                    AND (E.[AuditProjectID] = @AuditProjectId  
                         AND (E.[INTRNL_RTNG_CD] = @InternalRating 
                              OR @InternalRating = 0) 
                         AND (E.[ECNMC_ACTVTY_TXT] = @FilterEcActivity 
                              OR @FilterEcActivity = '') 
                         AND (@EconomicActivityClause) -- This all filters are on {ENTITI} table
                    AND (@InternalRatingClause) 
                    AND (@CntryClause) 
                    AND (@ImpsSttsClause) 
                    AND (@IntRatDiffClause)
                    AND (E.[ENTTY_NM] = @Entity OR @Entity = '') 
                    AND ((@HasDiffRating = 1 AND E.[INTRNL_RTNG_CD] <> E.[INTRNL_RTNG_PRVS_CD]) OR @HasDiffRating = 0)
                   )
INNER JOIN 
    {GCC} G ON (GE.[GCCID] = G.[ID])
INNER JOIN 
    {CNTRY} CN ON (E.[CNTRY] = CN.[ID])
LEFT JOIN 
    {IMPRMNT_STTS} IMPS ON (E.[IFRS_9_STAGE] = IMPS.[IFRS_9_STAGE]) 
                        -- AND (IMPS.[IMPRMNT_STTS_NM] = @ImpairmentStatus OR @ImpairmentStatus = '') 
LEFT JOIN 
    {ENTITI_CALC} EC ON (E.[ID] = EC.[ENTITYID]) 
WHERE
    ((IMPS.[IMPRMNT_STTS_NM] = @ImpairmentStatus OR @ImpairmentStatus = ''))
ORDER BY 
    @OrderBy 
    OFFSET @Skip ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY 

Condition in WHERE clause:
SELECT 
    E.[ENTITY_ID] ENTITY_ID, E.[ENTTY_NM] ENTTY_NM, 
    G.[PRNT_ID] GCC_ID, G.[PRNT_NM] GCC_NM, 
    E.[Buba_ID] BUBA_ID, E.[GRP_TTL_DBT] GRP_TTL_DBT, 
    E.[INTRNL_RTNG_CD] INTRNL_RTNG,
    COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM
    {ENTITI} E
INNER JOIN 
    {GCC_ENTITY} GE ON (E.[ID] = GE.[ENTITYID])
INNER JOIN 
    {GCC} G ON (GE.[GCCID] = G.[ID])
INNER JOIN 
    {CNTRY} CN ON (E.[CNTRY] = CN.[ID])
LEFT JOIN 
    {IMPRMNT_STTS} IMPS ON (E.[IFRS_9_STAGE] = IMPS.[IFRS_9_STAGE]) 
                        -- AND (IMPS.[IMPRMNT_STTS_NM] = @ImpairmentStatus OR @ImpairmentStatus = '') 
LEFT JOIN 
    {ENTITI_CALC} EC ON (E.[ID] = EC.[ENTITYID]) 
WHERE 
    (E.[AuditProjectID] = @AuditProjectId 
     AND (E.[INTRNL_RTNG_CD] = @InternalRating OR @InternalRating = 0) 
     AND (E.[ECNMC_ACTVTY_TXT] = @FilterEcActivity OR @FilterEcActivity = '') 
     AND (@EconomicActivityClause) 
     AND (@InternalRatingClause) 
     AND (@CntryClause) 
     AND (@ImpsSttsClause) 
     AND (@IntRatDiffClause)
     AND (E.[ENTTY_NM] = @Entity OR @Entity = '') 
     AND ((@HasDiffRating = 1 AND E.[INTRNL_RTNG_CD] <> E.[INTRNL_RTNG_PRVS_CD]) OR @HasDiffRating = 0)
         AND (IMPS.[IMPRMNT_STTS_NM] = @ImpairmentStatus OR @ImpairmentStatus = ''))
ORDER BY 
    @OrderBy 
    OFFSET @Skip ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY

We are working in OutSystems low code platform and we want improve the SQL query performance.

Do you have a question?

I would assume that, if there's a difference, the top one is faster. But you obviously have both, so why don't you try them out and see?

Are you sure you're using SQL Server? Syntax like AND (@EconomicActivityClause) and INNER JOIN {GCC_ENTITY} GE isn't valid T-SQL. SQL Server doesn't have a boolean data type, and T-SQL doesn't use braces as delimit identifiers.

The bottleneck here may be OFFSET pagination. Consider KEYSET pagination instead.

This Syntax is from OutSystems low-code platform. But ultimately we uses SQL Server. Please ignore the { } and those starting from @ are dynamic SQL query parameters.
Ex. @EconomicActivityClause = E.ENTTY_NM ='ABC'
Question is : Which will be faster Condition within JOIN or in WHERE?

See Is a JOIN faster than a WHERE? and Condition within JOIN or WHERE. You need to test it.

If you can substitute in a whole clause, it's NOT real query parameterization and you may still have injection vulnerabilities.

For what it's worth, it is more readable and understandable to have proper JOIN syntax, joining on the fields that establish the relationship(s) between the tables, and then applying your conditions in the WHERE clause that make your query distinct for the [business] purpose.
